# Aggregate SQL functions with irregular time stamps

Tags: mysql, sql, time-series

I have a table which includes a time stamp and river flow.  Some days I have multiple records, yet other days I have no records.

How can I calculate the average flow and total flow between two dates?

Assuming a linear value between two points is acceptable.  Maybe some sort of weighted average.  If there is some least squares regression algorithm or something similar which provides more accurate results, that would also be great.

EDIT.  For a given day I have the following fictional data for illustration purposes.  If possible, I would like to do better than assuming an average of 146 as the flows are high for longer duration's, and the real average is likely over 200.

```
10/12/15 12:00 AM   100
10/12/15 12:01 AM   102
10/12/15 12:02 AM   104
10/12/15 12:03 AM   106
10/12/15 12:04 AM   200
10/12/15 10:00 PM   204
10/12/15 11:00 PM   208

Average             146
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question. Do you simply want a weighted average/regression, or are you having technical issues with something you already have?

Comment: A least squares regression algorithm determines the best *linear* relationship between two variables, however you explicitly don't want to "assume a linear value between two points." So what kind of relationship do you want? Or is that the question? You have to assume something when converting discrete data into a continuous relationship.

Comment: @JulienBlanchard  A weighted average or regression would be good if they are possible.

Comment: @eirikir  No, I said a linear value "is" acceptable.  If a LSR is possible in SQL, I assume that would be better.  Just looking for anything available (and hopefully fast and simple).

Comment: What kind of value is being used for flow? Some sort of "x per second" and you want the total "x" in the timeframe?

Comment: @Uueerdo  The values are cfs (cubic feet per second).  I am looking for the average cfs and the total cubic feet between two dates.  I "could" first just do a normal average of the data and multiple that value by the time span, but if I have multiple records for a given day, those records will incorrectly bias the average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a weighted average.  For this, you need the next time stamp:

```
select rf.*,
       (select rf2.timestamp
        from riverflow rf2
        where rf2.timestamp > rf.timestamp
        order by rf.timestamp asc
        limit 1
       ) as nextTimestamp
from riverflow rf;
```

Next, comes the weighted average.  I have no idea how you want to handle the issue that the period of measurement may not align with given days.  Instead, we'll just take values and report on the beginning and ending observation times:

```
select min(timestamp) as start, max(timestamp) as end,
       (sum(riverflow * timestampdiff(second, timestamp, nexttimestamp) / (24*60*60)) /
        (timestampdiff(second, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)) / (24*60*60)
       ) as avgRiverflow
from (select rf.*,
             (select rf2.timestamp
              from riverflow rf2
              where rf2.timestamp > rf.timestamp
              order by rf2.timestamp asc
              limit 1
             ) as nextTimestamp
      from riverflow rf
      where timestamp >= $date1 and timestamp < $date2
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I think this does what I was hoping for.  I edit my original post to show the scenario of high flows for most of a given day.  It takes it into account, right?

Comment: @user1032531 . . . This should take the duration into account for the weighted average.

Comment: Haven't tested yet, but think this is the right approach.  Thank you Gordon.  PS.  Why do you think my question was downvoted?  I thought it was pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be generally the right direction:

```
SELECT AVG(dayflowRate) AS avgFlowRate, SUM(dayFlow) AS totalFlow
FROM (
SELECT DATE(theTS) AS theDate, AVG(flowRate) AS dayFlowRate
    , AVG(flowRate) * (24*60*60) AS dayFlow
FROM theTable
WHERE theTS BETWEEN [beginTS] AND [endTS]
GROUP BY theDate
) AS dayQ
;
```

However, it assumes full days with that `24 * 60 * 60` multiplier (*expanded only for clarity by the way*). If you need greater precision, you will want to look into MIN and MAX aggregations, and TIME_TO_SEC function.

I think this (below) might be a little more accurate:

```
SELECT AVG(dayflowRate) AS avgFlowRate, SUM(dayFlow) AS totalFlow
FROM (
SELECT DATE(theTS) AS theDate, AVG(flowRate) AS dayFlowRate
    , AVG(flowRate) 
      * ( TIME_TO_SEC(LEAST(MAX(theTS), [endTS]) 
          - TIME_TO_SEC(GREATEST(MIN(theTS), [beginTS]))
        )
      AS dayFlow
FROM theTable
WHERE theTS BETWEEN [beginTS] AND [endTS]
GROUP BY theDate
) AS dayQ
;
```

Edit: or might not, if that day's measurements are at 11am and 1pm, it's dayFlow will only actually be for two hours of flow, even if it is in the middle of multiple days.

This should be best:

```
SELECT AVG(dayflowRate) AS avgFlowRate, SUM(dayFlow) AS totalFlow
FROM (
SELECT DATE(theTS) AS theDate, AVG(flowRate) AS dayFlowRate
    , AVG(flowRate) 
      * ( IF(DATE(theTS)=DATE([endTS]), TIME_TO_SEC([endTS]), (24*60*60))
          - IF(DATE(theTS)=DATE([beginTS]), TIME_TO_SEC([beginTS]), 0)
        )
      AS dayFlow
FROM theTable
WHERE theTS BETWEEN [beginTS] AND [endTS]
GROUP BY theDate
) AS dayQ
;
```

Comment: Let's say I had readings of 100 at 12AM, 110 at 1AM, 200 at 2AM, and 210 at 11PM.  This would suggest an average of 155.  However, in reality the average is likely around 200 as the duration of times experiencing the higher flows is much longer.

Comment: That occurred to me, but I figured that kind of thinking made too many assumptions to be handled by a query. As a counterpoint, if the flow is 1000 at 6am and 100 at 10pm, assuming that 16 hour span was more of one than the other would be a mistake (in my opinion).